# Get sibling variable value from XPath - PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I am using the following to extract the number from html using xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP"></span><span class="foo" d="bar" itemprop="price">£100</span>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="price"]');
$number = filter_var($results->item(0)->nodeValue, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $number;
```

Question is, how can I get the `content` variable from `<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP">`?

I can use the following to get to the node:

```
$currency = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="priceCurrency"]');
```

But is there a way to get `content` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the `getAttribute()` method:

```php
$currency = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="priceCurrency"]')->item(0);
$content = $currency->getAttribute('content');
echo $content; // prints "GBP"
```